# ClientAuthenticationError when trying to upload a registered component to Azure ML using Python Azure ML SDK v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-pipelines, azureml-python-sdk

Would appreciate any help resolving the following issue, and if anyone knows a way to import a model from Azure Model Reigstry into Azure ML Pipelines.

I'm using the latest version of Azure ML SDK v2 and trying to upload a component to my workplace. I authenticated using the following to get a MLClient and workplace client:

```
subscription_id = "XXXX"
resource_group = "XXXX"
workspace_name = "XXXX"

credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential()
ml_client = MLClient(credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
workspace = ml_client.workspaces.get(name=ml_client.workspace_name)
```

I wrote a simple component in another Python file called `optimizer`, which I import and want to register.

```
from components import optimizer
ml_client.components.create_or_update(optimizer)
```

I get the following traceback error:

```
ClientAuthenticationError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21948\2530497008.py in <module>
      1 from components import optimizer
----> 2 ml_client.components.create_or_update(optimizer)

c:\Users\Alan\miniconda3\envs\azureml\lib\site-packages\azure\ai\ml\operations\_component_operations.py in create_or_update(self, component, version, skip_validation, **kwargs)
    294 
    295         # Create all dependent resources
--> 296         self._resolve_arm_id_or_upload_dependencies(component)
    297 
    298         component._update_anonymous_hash()

c:\Users\Alan\miniconda3\envs\azureml\lib\site-packages\azure\ai\ml\operations\_component_operations.py in _resolve_arm_id_or_upload_dependencies(self, component)
    439 
    440         # resolve component's code
--> 441         _try_resolve_code_for_component(component=component, get_arm_id_and_fill_back=get_arm_id_and_fill_back)
    442         # resolve component's environment
    443         if hasattr(component, "environment"):

c:\Users\Alan\miniconda3\envs\azureml\lib\site-packages\azure\ai\ml\operations\_component_operations.py in _try_resolve_code_for_component(component, get_arm_id_and_fill_back)
    603             with component._resolve_local_code() as code_path:
    604                 component.code = get_arm_id_and_fill_back(
--> 605                     Code(base_path=component._base_path, path=code_path), azureml_type=AzureMLResourceType.CODE
    606                 )
...

c:\Users\Alan\miniconda3\envs\azureml\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\response_handlers.py in <module>

ClientAuthenticationError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.'
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
```

I've made sure the firewall for my storage account accepts access from all networks, but the issue persists. Has anyone resolved this issue while using the SDK v2?

I expect my component to be registered to my Azure ML Workspace.